# Imported Shapefile layer doesn't show up in GRASS v.net dialog

Tags: qgis, qgis-grass-plugin

I am using the GRASS interface in QGIS 2.4. I have successfully imported my shapefiles into GRASS using v.in.ogr, but when I try to then use a GRASS tool, like v.net Network maintenance, the select boxes for choosing the imported vector layers are empty. Any suggestions? I can see the imported layers in the folder of my Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer here. You have to click **View output** which adds the GRASS layers to the QGIS map. Then the select boxes populate with the GRASS layers.